# Validation error deploying Azure Functions using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I am facing validation error while deploying Azure Functions using Azure DevOps. Please find the below error.

I am using `ARM template` and parameterized. If i provide a new `storage account` name am able to deploy from DevOps, if i use an existing storage account name, getting below error. Any suggestions?

> The template deployment 'azuredeploy-20200714-XXXXXX-gjhj' is not
> valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is
> 'XXXXXXXX'. See inner errors for details. Details:
> PreflightValidationCheckFailed: Preflight validation failed. Please
> refer to the details for the specific errors.
> [{"code":"InvalidValuesForRequestParameters","target":"","message":"Values
> for request parameters are invalid: kind."}] At least one resource
> deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for
> details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.
> Details: InvalidValuesForRequestParameters: Values for request
> parameters are invalid: kind. Check out the troubleshooting guide to
> see if your issue is addressed:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
> Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.

Comment: As a suggestion in order to determine if it has to do with the *Azure DevOps pipeline* or if it has to do with the *storage accounts*, could you try to do Publish or Zip Deploy using the new storage account and the existing storage account and check if you get any kind of errors?

Comment: If i provide new storage account name, the pipeline getting succeeded. But if i use the existing storage and deploy, getting failed with above error.(scenario : this is already existing function, i have done the code fix and deployed again using devops)

Comment: @user3401527 The error message indicated `Values for request parameters are invalid: kind`, did you specify correct type of storage account for the existing storage account?

Comment: @Cece Dong - MSFT Yes, I have used same storage account. To be clear : I have not changed any changes in DevOps release definition, checked in code fix in class file and created a new release. Existing settings configured in devops remains same

Comment: @user3401527 Do you mean you just change the storage account name, then the release works? Could you try to capture the fiddler trace (https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS) to see whether there is any useful information?

Comment: @Cece Dong - MSFT - No, I just modified the changes in Code , checked in and created release. During deployment am getting issue. Build in DevOps working fine. I have posted in AzureDevOps developer community and they mentioned as <we deteminded that this issue is related to Azure Product.>. Please find the link : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1112447/validation-error-deploying-azure-functions-using-a.html